# jQuery/js val() overwriting PHPs' $_POST['field']. How to fix?

Tags: php, jquery, input

I've got a pretty complicated (for me!) form validation to do. I did all js and now I'm doing php stuff.

The thing is I've put a possibility to copy part of the inputs to other, similar section (recipient -> payer). It's all done by jQuery first copying `$("input.payer_sth").val()` to `$("input.payer_sth")`, and then doing it again and again on keyup and blur.

All my inputs are built like that:

```
<input id="payer_name" name="payer_name" class="foo" type="text" value="<?=$_POST['payer_name']?>"/>
```

as long as the ones that aren't modified by jQuery work all right on submit and "back", the ones that has modified `val()` are empty on back.

What's obvious for me is that jQuery is overwriting `value="<?=$_POST['field']?>"` .

How can this be fixed?

Comment: I'm really struggling to understand what you're trying to do / ask here... your jQuery in your second paragraph wouldn't match the HTML example you've provided, the class name in the HTML is `foo` and you're selecting all inputs with class name `payer_sth` so they wouldn't be selected. You should probably start off focusing on identifying the exact problem i.e. whether it's in your PHP or your client-side stuff. I don't see this being a problem that can't be fixed with some simple `console.log's` / `var_dump's`.

Comment: So, when your page first loads you use jQuery to populate the field with a default value? If the the page is submitted and some validation fails, the page reloads and is supposed to repopulate with the $_POST value, but jQuery is overwriting the values?

Comment: jlindenbaum: that was exactly the issue, I've had a code snippet that checked if the values are to be copied or cleared and did that on reload, now everything seems to work just ok

Answer (score 0):

Based on my comments above, you may want to do this on server-side instead of client side.

Example (not the cleanest, but you'll get the point)

```
<input id="payer_name" name="payer_name" class="foo" type="text" value="<?= (!isset($_POST['player_name'])) ? 'Enter your name' : $_POST['payer_name']?>"/>
```

So what this will do, is if there is no post set it will output "Enter your name" into the field, if the $_POST is set it will output the value of the post into the field.

The construct is called a ternary operator: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

You can clean it up a bit on your side, but this will do the trick and it'll avoid the use of JavaScript for something like this where JS should not be required by the end-user.